# JAWS Screen Reader is jumping particlular element when navigating using key up/down?

Tags: jaws-screen-reader, wcag2.0, nvda

While we are using the up / down arrow key in the JAWS reader to read the content of the web pages will be moved to the top of the parent section after any actions have been completed. But it works fine by using the tab.

It works fine by using NVDA and Voiceover.

Comment: is there a question in here somewhere bud? JAWs is working as expected, what is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Our product works absolutely fine with NVDA and Voiceover. But with JAWS, It works fine when navigated through "Tab" button, but when navigated using "Arrow keys", the JAWS focus is getting shifted to the parent section instead of the actual navigatied element. (e.g. In a YouTube like environment,using "Arrow keys"in JAWS, We would navigate to a particular video and hit the "Watch later" button, after triggering the action, the JAWS focus moves to the parent sectio,which which is the Left navigation menu item).

Comment: Could you put up an example that doesn't work as you expect. My guess is you have a stray tabindex="0" or similar. But with the information provided it is only guesses that we can provide you with at the moment. Also JAWs does have some settings that can cause behaviour like this which is why an example makes it easier to diagnose.